# Oracle SQL To_Char(interval) is not using my format string?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following bit of SQL, I want to print an interval (actually a number of seconds) in HH:MM:SS format.  I convert the seconds to an Interval, then attempt to use TO_CHAR date formatting.  The Oracle server ignores my pattern and prints a whole timestamp with zero chars in dates and microseconds.  What am I doing wrong?

```
CASE WHEN (TR.RUN_LENGTH > 0) THEN TO_CHAR(NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second'), 'HH24:MI:SS')
ELSE '0' END AS RUN_LENGTH,
```

And I get:  +000000000 00:03:22.000000000

Comment: You have to use `SUBSTR` or `REGEXP_SUBSTRING`

Comment: What do you like to get for intervals longer than 24 hours?

Comment: I was about to recommend first casting to `interval day(2) to second(0)` then using `substr()` to take the 5th character onwards - however I see that now fails in 21c with *ORA-25137: Data value out of range*.

Comment: That was the previous developer's approach and it worked for them.  I just exposed it to a wider range of intervals (I had a job run multiple days) and it failed, leading me to this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed, `to_char()` doesn't work on intervals.  So, don't think in terms of intervals.  Instead, you have a number of seconds and you want to convert to a string in the format of HH:MM:SS.

Use arithmetic and string operations:

```
select lpad(floor(tr.run_length / 3600), 2, '0') || ':' || lpad(mod(floor(tr.run_length / 60),  60), 2, '0') || ':' || lpad(mod(tr.run_length, 60), 2, '0') as hhmmss
from (select 1 as run_length from dual union all
      select 10 as run_length from dual union all
      select 100 as run_length from dual union all
      select 1000 as run_length from dual union all
      select 10000 as run_length from dual union all
      select 100000 as run_length from dual 
     ) tr;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a603fcb75b5eda7b3338b7cceb4513a9) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I searched through the other Related responses; It's clear that Oracle doesn't actually implement a user specified format for TO_CHAR(DSINTERVAL).  As some have suggested, you can add a date then use the date formatting.  But that fails if the interval is more than 24 hours.

I ended up using REGEXP_SUBSTRING() but then ran into the problem that Oracle evidently doesn't support non-capturing groups.  I was able to piece together this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second')), '^([\+0:\ ]*)(.*)(\.)',1,1,NULL,2 )
```

which seems to work quite well.  It suppresses any leading zeros and fractional seconds.

Comment: I would suggest expression `'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'`

Answer (score 0):

If your interval is always less than 24 hours, then you can use one of these:

```
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH, 'second'), 'hh24:mi:ss')

REGEXP_SUBSTR(NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second'), '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

Otherwise you need to use the [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E) function:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second')) * 24 
       + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second')) )
   || ':' EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second') 
   || ':' TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(TR.RUN_LENGTH,'second'))
```

Optionally you have to add `LPAD(..., 2, '0')` around the parts, if required for your output.

Answer (score 0):

Less code:

```
to_number(
substr(to_char((LATER_timestamp - EARLIER_timestamp),'HH24:MI:SS'), 1,10) /* this is the DAY  string */ 
) || 'd ' ||
substr(to_char((LATER_timestamp - EARLIER_timestamp),'HH24:MI:SS'),12,11) /* this is the TIME string.  Milliseconds are "FLOORED". */
```

Example output is: "2d 02:59:57.31".

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE) + NUMTODSINTERVAL ((TR.RUN_LENGTH, 'second'),   
    'hh24:mi:ss' )
```

The doc for NUMTODSINTERVAL says it returns a string literal, so to_char has no effect.  This hack above just takes the current date/time (sysdate), truncates the HH:mm:ss component, then adds back the #seconds you specify, then format that to just show the HH:MM:SS value

Comment: Which doc? The function returns an interval, not a string.

Comment: But this hack works only for intervals less than 24 hours.

Comment: @mathguy,  That's was I assumed, but the doc says, "NUMTODSINTERVAL converts n to an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND literal."  calling, select  length( NUMTODSINTERVAL (100, 'second') ) from dual ; returns 29, then length of the return value.

Comment: @oldprogrammer Because [`length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LENGTH.html#GUID-8F97F652-5AE8-4457-AFD7-7A6F25551E0C) takes a character expression as input, so [interval datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C) gets converted to its string representation. The documentation for `numtodsinterval` has a misleading description, because it doesn't return any literal, but a value of built-in datatype